# Nightwatch.js - Getting title of element and compare it later

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I'm using Nightwatch.js for E2E testing.

In the test, there should be a click on specific element in a table list to select an article. Then the article gets loaded.

Now I want to check if the correct article has been loaded by comparing the title.

How do I get the text of the selected element? In my code, the element is just clicked. In the second part, this title should be compared. In my code below, it is just hard coded:

```
module.exports = {
  'article': function(browser) {
    browser
      .click('#list tbody tr:first-child .selectable')
      .waitForElementVisible('#article-wrapper', 10000)

    browser.expect.element('h1').text.to.equal('specific title')

    browser.end()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question well, I think you need to use the [`getText`](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#getText) method. I do not know the structure of your HTML code, but this minimal working example will certainly help you:

**HTML** (*index.html*)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nightwatch</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Foo</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript** (*title.js*)

```
module.exports = {
  'Title': function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost:8000/index.html') // Change this if needed
      .waitForElementPresent('body', 1000);

    browser.getText('table tr:last-child td:first-child', function (title) {
      browser.expect.element('h1').text.to.equal(title.value);
    });

    browser.end();
  }
};
```

**Command**

```
nightwatch -t tests/title.js
```

Comment: I think you are a bit misunderstanding: First I need to get the text of the table element. Then nightwatch is doing a click on it, which will route to another page. The title of this page should be compared to the text which is extracted from the table before.

Comment: This is what I understood, except that I thought you were using AJAX. However, from my perspective, this basic example with `getText` is still clear enough to solve your problem. What's blocking you?